# iText with giant Chapter

Tags: java, itext

I have a problem with write a PDF.

I have a multiple giant texts, each text will be a section on my pdf. This sections will be put in chapter, and the chapter will be put in PDF.

But when I make:

```
document.add(chapter);
```

It's so slow.

Someone can help me?

Comment: Giant texts take giant time. Unfortunately your description does not allow to reproduce or measure the issue.

Comment: So, this is the problem, the texts has a 6 Mb, and I have 11 texts. Each text are converted in Inputstream. Each text will be put in section like describe.

Comment: Do you make use of the `LargeElement` mechanism in iText? `Chapter` does implement that interface...

Comment: I can produce chapter, the slow operation is when I need put chapter in document, as document.add(chapter)

Comment: Obviously, adding to the document does take more time than abstractly defining the chapter. What exactly do you mean by *slow*, how long does it take?

Comment: The answer is simple: stop using `Chapter`. The only reason why you'd use `Chapter`, is to create bookmarks. Creating bookmarks can easily be done using `PdfOutline`.

Comment: @Bruno I'm not sure it is so simple... it simply takes some time to add 66 MB of text to a document, and the OP has not yet indicated what *slow* means.

Comment: @mkl OK, allow me to rephrase. If you create a large `Chapter` containing 66 MB of text in memory first, then add that `Chapter` to a `Document`, then the process will be much *slower* than adding 66 MB of text in small portions. Adding 66 MB of text in small portions will keep the memory footprint low and you will also gain in processing time. So if the OP wants to make his application *faster*, he should not use the `Chapter` object, regardless of his answer to the question *What is slow?* ;-)

Comment: Slow: 30 minutes to add 66MB of text.